# Detecting mouse events on Kinetic.Line

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to detect mouse events (currently mousedown) on a `Kinetic.Group` containing a grid made of `Kinetic.Line's`

I'm listening to the mousedown event on the Layer. When it happens that i hit a line, no event is fired.

```
var grid = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: this.group.width(),
    height: this.group.height()
});

grid.on("mousedown", function(){
    alert("At least this one should fire!");
});

var gridX = this.gridWidth, gridY = this.gridHeight;

this.group.add(grid);

while(gridY < this.rect.height()){          

    var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points : [0,gridY, this.rect.width(), gridY],
        stroke: "grey",
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    grid.add(line);

    gridY += this.gridHeight;
}

while(gridX < this.rect.width()){           
    var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points : [gridX,0, gridX, this.rect.height()],
        stroke: "grey",
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    grid.add(line);

    gridX += this.gridWidth;
}
```

I found this post:

[Kinetic.Line mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762499/kinetic-line-mouseover)

The answer mentioned there is using "saveData()" on the shape. This seems to be old because this method does not exist in `Kinetic.Shape`.

The example where the above post is pointing to is for images. And it uses the `cache()` method to create a hit graph or something. I tried that for my lines but this won't work either.

How can i simply detect mouse events on a Kinetic.Line?

Comment: You should be able to bind a click event on a layer like this `clickLayer.on('click', function(evt) { // Do something });`

Comment: i added a code snippet so it is more clear what i'm doing

Comment: Maybe you could put it in a jsFiddle, so we have something to play with

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are still looking for an answer to this @Chris, and in case others find your thread, I believe you and I were suffering from the same issue. @Sjiep so graciously provided a fix for my problem under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23257415/1558855) thread.

Turns out it was indeed a bug!